# DB4O database size growing on updating objects

Tags: java, database, db4o

I've a java web server application which updates objects to the database every 10 seconds or so.

I've noticed that when updating, even if no changes are applied,almost every time the size of the database grows a few KB's.

I've used their example here:
http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.0/java/tutorial/docs/Structured.html#outline39

I tried to [defrag](http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-6.1/net2/reference/html/db4o_Database_Management/Maintenance/Defragment.html) the database but this does not reduce to its original size with the same amount of objects in it.

Can anyone tell me how to prevent this/what I'm possibly doing wrong?

EDIT:

This is the part of my code where I update or store a object (Device in this case):

```
        try {
        LinkedList<Device> lDevices = Sense.getDevices();
        if (lDevices.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        db = Db4o.getDatabaseClient();

        for (Device device : lDevices) {
            List<Device> query = db.queryByExample(new Device(device.getDeviceId()));

            if (query.size() == 1) {
                //store changes
                Device found = query.get(0);

                found.setBatteryLevel(device.getBatteryLevel());
                found.setLastknownLocation(device.getLastknownLocation());
                found.setType(device.getType());

                db.store(found);
            } else {
                // store new Device
                db.store(device);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        if (db instanceof ObjectContainer) {
            db.close();
        }
    }
```

But now I found out using the Eclipse plugin db4o database browser that the Location class which is in a Device object is updated AND stored again in the database.

So I have 2 Devices and 2 Locations in the database at first, after the first update there are 2 Devices and 4 Locations in the database!! This is driving me nuts!

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: If device.getLastknownLocation() returns an object that was not retrieved from the db it'll be stored (since db4o believes it is a new object).

Comment: OK, the solution I found is that in-dept-objects need to be removed first or they will be stored twice.
Thanks to both Vagaus and Gamlor for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to check:

Do you assign new objects and collections (which are not stored yet) to fields of the update objects. Then db4o will take those objects and store them as well. But the object which was referenced before stays in the database unless you delete it.

This isn't the case for 'value' objects like Strings and primitives.

Anyway in general I would expect that the database first grows. The reason is that db4o stores a updated at a new location. However the old location should be marked as free and be reused for new objects / other updates. At least when de-fragmenting the space should be freed.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code I use to update the database. Could you please tell me if you know how I could fix this?

Comment: It looks like my problem is your first point. The object 'Location' in 'Device' is not from the database.

Now I tried this:
// remove old object first from db
db.delete(found.getLastknownLocation());
found.setLastknownLocation(device.getLastknownLocation());

The database still grows, but gets smaller, almost its original size after defragmenting. I quess this is the way to update in-dept-objects like 'Location' in my 'Device' object?

Answer (score 0):

When you update objects db4o will in fact duplicate them and put the space used for the "old" object in a list of free space.

Whenever a write comes again db4o will try to reuse space from this "*free space*".

So this growth is expected.

Best

Adriano